# apache redirection for URL

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting, redirect

For most of the websites URL if I type `www.example.com` in the address bar of a browser, it gets changed to `http://example.com` . I want that redirection from `www` to `http` should not happen . If a user tyes `www.example.com` in the browser , then the URL should remain as `www.example.com` . Similarly if somebody types `http://example.com` , then the URL should remain as `http://example.com` . This is a requirement from one of the user . Not sure whether this is achievable.We are using `apache` for `Web Server`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "http://" to your input is not an HTTP redirect, it's your browser making your input something a bit more uniform/accurate.

Comment: Adding http is not a issue for me. But www is getting omitted. Is it possible to prevent that by using any Apache configuration

Comment: It's only done by explicit configuration. Search your configuration.

Comment: Can you please tell which Apache directive I need to check. Is it parameters for server name / server alias etc

Comment: Rewriterule or redirect